# doesnt have any certificate/private key pair

Tags: objective-c

I have been given an ad hoc distribution provisioning profile by my manager but when i am tring to select it it is saying that the profile dosent match with any certificate/private key pair in keychain.(when looked in  -> build->code signing identity -> any os

Answer (score 1):

Ad hoc distribution provisioning profiles will not enable you to sign any code. Instead, it allows you to install and run a particular app (or a handfull of apps, depending on the settings) signed for ad hoc distribution. The profile specifies which devices the app may be run on. 
You are going to import the profile and the app to iTunes and sync your iPhone to use it.

The advantage of ad hoc distribution is that you do not need to publish an app to the AppStore to distribute it, so you can quickly test minor changes on some beta tester devices. You may use this way to distribute the app to up to 100 unique devices per year. 
One downside is of course that Apple cannot take care of updating and distributing your app. You have to do that manually. Furthermore, you are restricted to the 100 devices and you cannot sell your app.

Comment: then what should i do in order to run my game with adhoc provisioning profile.Ectually the game was developed by my colleague and now he has left the company so i am suppose to take the charge for the app.but when i am running the app by the adhoc distribution profile then it is saying that Raj's(previous employee) certificate/private key pair not found in defualt key chain.

Comment: Import the profile and the game (.ipa file) to iTunes and sync your device!